# sys.path must be a list of directory names with paramiko?

Tags: python, paramiko

I am making ssh connect to my IP address using paramiko and then i do execute certain commands in the loop. Previously this worked fine but now this throw exception

```
logging.basicConfig()
paramiko_logger = logging.getLogger("paramiko.transport")
paramiko_logger.disabled = True
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ipaddress = '169.254.30.39'
ssh.connect(ipaddress, port=22, username='root', password='')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Audio_connect.py", line 100, in <module>
    Audio_connect_class('43210')
  File ".\Audio_connect.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.getreorderedzip(reorder)
  File ".\Audio_connect.py", line 34, in getreorderedzip
    self.execute(zip(newinput,newtestcasenames))
  File ".\Audio_connect.py", line 44, in execute
    ssh.connect(ipaddress, port=22, username='root', password='')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 392, in connect
    t.start_client(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 545, in start_client
    raise e
RuntimeError: sys.path must be a list of directory names
```

When i print sys.path this print my folderlocation in which my file is, whereas i know sys.path usually prints list of all dependency folder. I tried almost everything and went through already asked queries on stackoverflow but nothing has helped me.

*****EDIT********
Working Code

```
import paramiko, os, sys, time
import Audio_connect_Input
from LogFille import writelogfile

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('169.254.30.39', port=22, username='root', password='')

channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

channel_data = str()
MainConnectionId= str()
isError = False

input =[
       Audio_connect_Input.A,
        Audio_connect_Input.B,
        Audio_connect_Input.C,
        Audio_connect_Input.D,
        Audio_connect_Input.E
        ]
testcaseNames = [
                'A',
                'B',
                'C',
                'D',
                'E'
                ]

key = str()
elem = str()

#while True:
for (x,name) in zip(input,testcaseNames):
 .... Execution steps...

sys.path result 
C:\XYZ_CLI\cli_testexecutions
E:\python27
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\python27.zip
E:\Python27\DLLs
E:\Python27\lib
E:\Python27\lib\plat-win
E:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
E:\Python27\lib\site-packages
```

******Non Working Code******

```
import paramiko, os, sys, time
from LogFille import writelogfile
import logging
import Audio_connect_Input

class Audio_connect_class(object):
    def __init__(self, reorder):
        print '__init___ ', sys.path
        self.getreorderedzip(reorder)

    def getreorderedzip(self, reorder):
        print ''

        input =[
           Audio_connect_Input.A,
            Audio_connect_Input.B,
            Audio_connect_Input.C,
            Audio_connect_Input.D,
            Audio_connect_Input.E
            ]
        testcaseNames = [
                    'A',
                    'B',
                    'C',
                    'D',
                    'E'
                    ]

        newinput = []
        newtestcasenames = []
        for idx in reorder:
            newinput.append(input[int(idx)])
            newtestcasenames.append(testcaseNames[int(idx)])
        self.execute(zip(newinput,newtestcasenames))

    def execute(self, received_zip):
        logging.basicConfig()
        paramiko_logger = logging.getLogger("paramiko.transport")
        paramiko_logger.disabled = True
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        ipaddress = '169.254.30.39'
        ssh.connect(ipaddress, port=22, username='root', password='')

        channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

        channel_data = str()
        MainConnectionId= str()
        isError = False

        key = str()
        elem = str()

        #while True:
        for (x,name) in received_zip:
            ****Execution Steps*****

sys.path result 
C:\XYZ_CLI\cli_testexecution_as_class
```

Both filename are same bur kept in different folder.

Comment: do you change sys.path in your program? it should remain a list.

Comment: Nope, i didn't wrote any such line to either append or insert sys.path

Comment: can you check `PYTHONPATH` env. variable?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't have PYTHONPATH  set. I never used any. I am using windows10 where in path section i have set are python27 and python27/scripts folder.

Comment: soiund like a bug. Which version of python 2.7 are you using? (minor revision I mean)

Comment: I was trying with python 2.7.9 but just now i installed 2.7.14 and tried the same. I am getting same issue

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have added code which works fine but same when i have structured in class file and it is throwing weird exception.

Comment: can you print `sys.path` in both cases and edit in your question?

Comment: Yeas Added, my code is in C drive but my new python 2.7.14 is in e: drive. for non working one i can't see other folder list

Comment: what is strange is that in the working example you have a file in the path: `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\python27.zip`... anyway, it would be better if you printed the variable without looping on it, so we can see it's type, etc... you could also try to set it to `sys.path = []` and see what happens.

Comment: ['C:\\XYZ_CLI\\cli_testexecutions', 'E:\\python27', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'E:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'E:\\Python27\\lib', 'E:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'E:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'E:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']  without looping but when i do sys.path = [] i get File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 545, in start_client
    raise e
ImportError: No module named calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after digging a lot of time in to the hassle I figured out that `from LogFille import writelogfile` was internally performing `os.sys.path = os.getcwd()` which was changing sys.path making it exception for paramiko to handle while accessing libraries at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

### Background

Paramiko 1.x is not working adequately for my use case.

Paramiko 2.11.0 depends on PyNaCl-1.4.0, which seems to have a failing dep.

Installing Paramiko 2.11.0 on Pythonista for iOS platform requires additional steps due to permission issues, missing dependencies, and an unused import.

I've listed my solution for my specific platform of iOS, I am not sure how much of it may be applicable to other platforms. Further down, is a partial solution that I bailed on once I found the answer specific to my own use.

### Solution for Pythonista (iOS)

Change launch_stash.py, line 1 from

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

to

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Reinstall Paramiko,

```
pip uninstall paramiko
pip install paramiko
```

It chokes on the PyNaCl package without error. After a normal amount of time, simply crash the app. Restart and run Stash. Install additional dependencies:

```bash
pip install asn1
```

Import Paramiko will crash due to missing (inaccessible?) util.py.

Copy the whole module into site-packages3 using `cp`. (The original location of the module is shown in the error message.)
This fixes the util import, and it allows you to modify the files.

stfp_client.py, line 32 change

```bash
from paramiko.pycompact import bytestring, b, u, long, string_types, byte_types
```

to

```bash
from paramiko.pycompact import b, u, long, string_types, byte_types
```

Now verify it works,

```py
import paramiko
print(paramiko.__version_info__) # (2, 11, 0)
```

If you need this to be simpler, please request, and I may combine all these steps into a single .tar.gz file, and link it here.

### Untested General Purpose Solution

(1) Acquire PyNaCl as a tar.gz.

Get the [same version I am using](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/5a/25aeb636baeceab15c8e57e66b8aa930c011ec1c035f284170cacb05025e/PyNaCl-1.4.0.tar.gz) (1.4.0, recommended) OR get the [latest](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/22/27582568be639dfe22ddb3902225f91f2f17ceff88ce80e4db396c8986da/PyNaCl-1.5.0.tar.gz) (1.5.0).

Extract using `tar -xzf PyNaCl-1.4.0`.

(2) PyNaCl-1.4.0, setup.py, line 32:

```py
from setuptools.command.build_clib import build_clib as _build_clib
```

Produces the error *sys.path must be a list of directory name*.

However, line 45 provides an alternative import that worked for me. It was meant to be triggered by a try/except, but it was too specific.

Change PyNaCl-1.4.0, setup.py, line 33 from

```py
except ImportError:
```

to

```py
except: # ImportError, RuntimeError
```

(3) Perform manual install of PyNaCl.

```bash
python3 setup.py install
```

I haven't tested much beyond this point. There were still some errors, but some of that was related to mistakenly using a python2-only session of stash (bashlike).